# C# .NET Core api authentication default value during debugging

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, swagger

We're developing an API and it uses authentication.

During development and debugging I'm constantly starting the api, sending requests with postman etc. But we also use Swagger and I would like to be able to just click on some GetMethods to free up my postman tabs a little.

I know this goes against what authentication is about, but can i set a default user or a default token? I know I can add authentication to swagger and paste in the token, but I would need to do this every time.

I would assume there'd be a simple option to set a default during debugging, but I cant find anything. Is it just not possible?

I also thought about simply not using Authentication when started in debug, but a lot of controller actions need the logged in user.

Comment: Ye the not using Authentication is the way I would go, and a logged-in user I'm sure that can easily be mocked

Comment: What I do is to set the authentication in Postman and then inherit that authentication, this way you can even automate the login process and you don't have to keep setting up the authentication tokens.  The number of tabs in Postman is quite a small price to pay.  In Swagger, once you authenticate it remains available until you close that session so only needs entering once per session.  It's important you don't start bypassing the authentication in your code as this is what leads to security failures and poor testing.